# Getting a "The page isn't redirecting properly" in my Spring-MVC application

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-security, apache-tiles

I'm trying to implement a Spring Security application. Also, I'm using tiles in my web-app.
Here is my Spring Security XML (spring-security.xml)

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
        <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here is my tiles.xml for login JSP page:

```
<definition name="login" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Login Here" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="loginContainer" type="definition" />
</definition>
<definition name="loginContainer" template="/layouts/loginPage.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="loginForm" value="/login.jsp" />
</definition>
```

And below is my login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<h3>Login Page</h3>
<form:form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">
    <input type="text" name="j_username"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="j_password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form:form>
```

Please let me know how its getting redirected endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had mistakenly put

```
<intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

Now changed it to:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_USER" />
```